# How do you configure registration lifetimes/settings using types in Autofac?

Tags: c#, autofac

I have different Interfaces which are supposed to describe the registration of services.

So far I only had two variations

```cs
public interface ISingletonElement {}
public interface ITransientElement {}
```

Which was easy enough to just have two different registrations like

```
builder
    .RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
    .AssignableTo<IService>()
    .AssignableTo<ISingletonElement>()
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .SingleInstance();
builder
    .RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
    .AssignableTo<IService>()
    .AssignableTo<ITransientElement>()
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .InstancePerDependency();
```

But lets say I want to have a more precise description with interfaces like

```
public interface IAutowiredElement {}
```

I obviously could just have more registration blocks. But that would get messy really fast.

```
// ..
    .AssignableTo<IService>()
    .AssignableTo<ISingletonElement>()
    .AssignableTo<IAutowiredElement>()

// ..
    .AssignableTo<IService>()
    .AssignableTo<ISingletonElement>()
    .Except<IAutowiredElement>()

// and so on ..
```

So my idea was to do something like

```
// pseudo code
builder
    .RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
    .AssignableTo<IService>()
    .Do(e => {
        if (e is IAutowiredElement)
        {
            e.PropertiesAutowired()
        }
        if (e is ISingletonElement) 
        {
            e.SingleInstance()
        }
        // ...
    });
```

Comment: Consider using an attribute rather than an interface. In the attribute have a boolean property for `AutoWired` and an enum property for lifetime scope.

Comment: @mjwills I actually like that idea. But I assume it isn't a solution to my problem, is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the comments that if you're going to use code-based metadata to indicate registration information that attributes are a better choice. The point of attributes is to carry type metadata around; marker interfaces aren't generally a good idea for that sort of thing.

A [quick Google search on 'autofac attribute based registration'](https://www.google.com/search?q=autofac+attribute+based+registration) pulls up [a nice library that someone has written](https://github.com/droyad/Autofac.AttributeRegistration) that does what it appears you're looking for. There are people out there trying to do what you're describing; I'd recommend not reinventing the wheel if you can avoid it.

That said, there are reasons Autofac doesn't ship with attributes out of the box and they're something to consider as you build up your solution:

- Changing the lifetime scope of a component shouldn't require you to change the component. Adding the attribute to the component itself means the person consuming the component doesn't get to make the choice about how they use it. What if you mark it as a singleton but the consumer needs it to be used one instance per web request? How do they change that?
- Dependency injection frameworks / inversion of control containers should generally only be at the "composition root" of your application. That's basically the app startup class. Accessing the container or spreading DI-specific metadata through the app isn't generally considered good practice. It makes the code far less portable and usable.

Regardless, if you still choose to go with an attribute-based solution, I'd recommend trying to find something out there that exists, even if you fork it and start from there.